# Why useState hook don't update while using loop inside useEffect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

Case 1:

```
    const [present, setPresent] = useState([]);
     
    useEffect(() => {
    
        for (var j = 1; j <= totalPeriod; j++) {
          setPresent([
            ...present,
            {
              period: j,
              present: true,
            },
          ]);
        }
    
    }, []);
```

Case 2:

```
    const [present, setPresent] = useState([]);
    
    let createPresent = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= totalPeriod; j++) {
      createPresent = [
        ...createPresent,
        {
          period: j,
          present: true,
        },
      ]
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setPresent(createPresent);
    }, []);
```

When I am trying to update the **present** state using loop in inside `useEffect()` in Case 1, **present** state is not updating. But when I am separately using loop outside the `useEffect()` and creating an array which I am then assigning to **present** state in case 2, the **present** state is getting updated.

What is the reason behind this? Why **present** state is not updating in Case 1?

Answer (score 8):

In the below case, your `present` state is not the result of each subsequent state update but rather the initial one which you had which is `[]`. React will **batch** these updates and not make them happen synchronously so effectively there will be just one state update with `present` updated to latest entry in your `for loop`.

```
  const [present, setPresent] = useState([]);
     
    useEffect(() => {
    
        for (var j = 1; j <= totalPeriod; j++) {
          setPresent([
            ...present,
            {
              period: j,
              present: true,
            },
          ]);
        }
    
    }, []);
```

In the below case, you are first assembling a `createPresent` array with all the values you need and finally calling the **state updator function** i.e. `setPresent` to set the state.

```
const [present, setPresent] = useState([]);
    
    let createPresent = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= totalPeriod; j++) {
      createPresent = [
        ...createPresent,
        {
          period: j,
          present: true,
        },
      ]
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setPresent(createPresent);
    }, []);
```

In order to achieve the second behaviour with first, you can make use of the **state updator callback which holds the previous state as the argument** like so :-

```
  const [present, setPresent] = useState([]);
     
    useEffect(() => {
    
        for (let j = 1; j <= totalPeriod; j++) {
          setPresent(prevState=>[
            ...prevState,
            {
              period: j,
              present: true,
            },
          ]);
        }
    
    }, []);
```

Here also state update is **batched** but previous state is factored in before updating the next one.

When I say a **batched** state update, I mean there will only be a single render. You can verify that by doing `console.log('render')` in your component's function body.

Note the use of `let` instead of `var` here since `let` is scoped you will get the accurate value for the variable `j`.

Comment: This solved it for me. Thank you Lakshya!

Answer (score 3):

The assumption you're making in Case 1 is that the `setPresent` call is synchronous and that it updates `present` immediately, while in reality state updates in React are almost always asynchronous. Thus the `present` variable inside `for (var j = 1; j <= totalPeriod; j++) {` will be equal to the original value, which is an empty array `[]`. So in essence, you're setting the state to this over and over:

```
  [
      ...[],
     {
        period: j,
        present: true,
     },
  ]
```

This will result in your state being updated to the last array the `for` loop creates. So if `totalPeriod` is equal to 5, your state will end up being `[{period: 5, present: true}]` instead of `[{period: 1, present: true}, {period: 2, present: true}, ... ]`

In Case 2, everything is very straightforward, you assemble the array without messing with state variables and then set the state in one shot. Just like you're supposed to in this case.

Comment: Let's suppose we have totalPeriod = 3, you mean that it will never be updated?

Comment: @Blessing It doesn't matter what `totalPeriod` is, `present` will always end up being the last object the for loop produces. So if it's 3, `present` will end up being `{period: 3, present: true}`

Comment: @codermonkey If I get well what you mean, you're saying that because `state` is `asynchronous` the first iteration will happen and if it tries to update the state it'll fail because the `state` won't be updated immediately and then the whole loop will end without updating the `state` right?

Comment: @Blessing You're almost correct. `setPresent` is asynchronous and as a result only the last operation of the loop will actually get registered with it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers:

You need to keep some key points in your mind while updating states in React component.
First of all updating state in React state is not synchronous, hence will be batched unless you trigger it asynchronously.

```
state = { count: 0};
increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    console.log(this.state.count) // 0
}

increment() 
console.log(this.state.count); // 1
```

And, the final value of this.state.count will be 1 after completion of the calling `incemenent()`

Because React batch the all calls up, and figure out the result and then efficiently make that change. Kind of this pure JavaScript code, merging where last one wins

```
newState = Object.assign(
    {},
    firstSetStateCall,
    secondSetStateCall,
    thirdSetStateCall,
);
```

So, we can say here everything has to do with JavaScript object merging. So there's another cool way, where we pass a function in setState instead of object.

Secondly, in case of react hooks `useState`, the `updating function`(second element of the array returned by useState()) doesn't rerender on the content's change of the state object, the reference of the state object has to be changed. For example: here I created sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-swanson-vjjnx)

had I not changed the reference of the array (which is the state), it would not rerender the components.

```
 for (let key in newState) {
      newStateToBeSent[key] = newState[key]; // chnaging the reference
    }
```